# Понизить роль пользователя через некоторое количество времени

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть стандартная роль пользователя `subscriber`. Роли пользователя будут изменяться на `man1`, `man2`, `man3` и тд. Можно ли сделать так, что бы через 30 дней как у пользователя изменилась роль с `subscriber`, его автоматически возвращало на `subscriber`, вне зависимости от роли которая была до этого?

Comment: добавить кастомное юзеру поле куда писать дату-время

Comment: @SeVlad А как изменить роль пользователя если от этого времени прошло 30 дней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой протестированный код выполняет задачу.

На хуках добаления или удаления роли пользователя он записывает текущее время в usermeta. При каждом init считывает эти usermeta. Если есть и они старше, чем 30 дней, то роль пользователя сменяется на subscriber.

```
<?php

/**
 * Add user role action.
 *
 * @param int $user_id The user ID.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function kagg_add_user_role( $user_id ) {
    $meta_key = 'role_changed_time';
    $user     = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles, true ) && ! get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, time() );
    }
}

add_action( 'add_user_role', 'kagg_add_user_role', 10 );

/**
 * Remove user role action.
 *
 * @param int    $user_id The user ID.
 * @param string $role    The removed role.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function kagg_remove_user_role( $user_id, $role ) {
    $meta_key = 'role_changed_time';

    if ( 'subscriber' === $role && ! get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, time() );
    }
}

add_action( 'remove_user_role', 'kagg_remove_user_role', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Check users which role has to be reset to subscriber.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function kagg_check_user_roles() {
    global $wpdb;

    $meta_key = 'role_changed_time';
    $time     = time();

    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery, WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.NoCaching
    $users_data = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT user_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key=%s",
            $meta_key
        )
    );

    foreach ( $users_data as $user_data ) {
        if ( ( $time - (int) $user_data->meta_value ) > 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
            remove_action( 'add_user_role', 'kagg_add_user_role' );
            remove_action( 'remove_user_role', 'kagg_remove_user_role' );

            $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_data->user_id );
            $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
            delete_user_meta( $user_data->user_id, $meta_key );

            add_action( 'add_user_role', 'kagg_add_user_role', 10 );
            add_action( 'remove_user_role', 'kagg_remove_user_role', 10, 2 );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'kagg_check_user_roles' );
```

Comment: А зачем wpdb? Есть же $WP_User->get( $key )

Comment: Ради проверки сменила на 1 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS и не отрабатывает. Или есть какие то индивидуальные моменты, которые я должна изменить при интеграции на сайт?

Comment: Не туда поставили, не так используете. Код рабочий, я его дебажил.

Comment: @SeVlad WP_User работает с одним пользователем. А я делаю запрос по всем пользователям сразу.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Все работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @KAGGDesign Подскажите пожалуйста, могу ли я как то, как администратор, менять вручную дату в 'role_changed_time' через ACF Date Time Picker?

Comment: В базе можно править запись в таблице usermeta.